# Did the original Super Mario Bros. contain a running glitch?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I've found a version of Super Mario Bros online. However, the game contains a glitch. If you run continuously, Mario's legs will stop moving for half a second or so, while he is still moving forward. Did this happen in the original NES version of the game as well?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic since the linked version is not legal, and illegal games are off-topic here.

Comment: @bwarner Sorry, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [don't](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Bros./Glitches) [think](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aISDPtWUVk0) so. Could just be a glitch with the port.

Comment: At [1:47](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aISDPtWUVk0&t=1m47s) it looks like your glitch, just in a wall. Related?

Comment: That's the moonwalking glitch. It refers to holding down left and repeatedly jumping, not "running continuously." http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Bros./Glitches#Moonwalking_through_the_Wall

Comment: @Pureferret My glitch occurs on World 1-2 when you just run at the top of the screen.